# Using external hard drive as installation medium for an Arch installation onto a laptop

Tags: arch-linux

After several attempts at achieving the goal pointed to in the title to this question I have not been successful.

The Arch Linux installation guide doesn't explicitly mention the procedure I'm attempting.

My Google searches are coming up very scant indeed.

ChatGPT has been helpful but still I'm falling short.

The external drive has an iso image saved.

The installation process works fine and yesterday I got to "the end". However I can't boot into the system. I'm getting the Arch BIOS screen only.

On one particular website the writer mentioned changing some BIOS settings. I think he mentioned disabling secure boot, UEFI legacy mode, and some other things. I could do with some clarity here.

I believe there is something called 'microcode' or something similar which is a consideration when using an external drive for the install. Again, I could do with some clarity here.

Do I have to prepare the hard drive in any particular way? I simply wiped it, formatted it, and saved the Arch iso to it.

There is a command mentioned on Arch's installation guide which tells which of [BIOS, UEFI, etc] is being used. I believe the output indicates I'm using BIOS.

I wish to install Arch on the *entire* 'internal' hard drive.

There are numerous formatting, mounting, BIOS configurations/files, and so on mentioned in the Arch installation guide. What if any of these procedures are different in my particular case?

In short, and where possible, I'm looking for a comprehensive procedure for installing Arch Linux according to my requirements and specifications.

I'm asking here only to save many further hours of potentially fruitless work.

I'd appreciate some help with this.

Kind regards..

P.S. the drive is GPT at my last check.

Comment: Can you clearly mark or remove all things that you found no better source than chatgpt for? ChatGPT simply makes things up, and it's really not worth your or our time wading through that. Let's stick with what you personally found in sources that to your best impression seem knowledgeable on the topic, mostly the arch wiki I'd say.

Comment: Hello Marcus, I appreciate your reply. 

The Arch Installation Guide mentions only USB Flash, Optical disk, and Network installs. I visited several links but I couldn't find sufficient clarification on using a HDD. This is one reason I used ChatGPT (and you are right about C-GPT's accuracy) I was mainly using ChatGPT simply as a time saving aid for various things, such as using various tools for partitioning and so on. I was checking it's answers against docs and web searches and so on. The official guide is my primary reference. The official literature.. CONTINUES ON NEXT COMMENT..

Comment: may well provide all the answers I need. However I'm not sufficiently experienced to grok it all into a solution; and I've spend many hours already on the general matter of getting the OS installed, as well as, several hours on the various issues I'm facing. I ask here out of respect for the community therefore. I hope I'm not being premature asking on the forum rather than reading more docs. In short the docs are serving me well except for lack of clarity on the peculiarities of my choice of installation procedure (BIOS setup, HDD preparation) + others unknown to me as of yet.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies things :) but I do really want to confirm that with "installation media" you mean the storage device you install *from*, not *on*, right? I'm getting a bit of mixed information there; usually, *installation medium* would be the thing that carries the installer, that's why I ask

Comment: Yes, I'm using the term 'installation medium' to mean (in my case) the external HDD storing the Arch '.iso' image - the storage device I'll be installing 'from'. 

Please do not hesitate to ask me any questions at all so I can provide absolute clarity where I may have fallen short. Or any other information whatsoever you may need.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense! So, you say "Arch bios screen", but there's no such thing as an "arch bios", is it possible you mean the Arch boot loader screen, where you can select an Arch linux to boot, among other things?

Comment: If system is less than 10 years old, you will want UEFI install on gpt partitioned drive. I directly boot ISOs from external drives or from a different internal drive using grub2's loopmount. I also have just created a FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags & extracted ISO with p7zip to make UEFI bootable flash drive. Have not used Arch so do not know its details. To boot ISO you need grub installed to a drive. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition  & https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multiboot_USB_drive#GParted_Live

Comment: Marcus - Yes, It is the Arch boot loader screen I'm seeing. I'm going to try another way. I'm installing Ubuntu to the laptop. I'll then attempt to successfully follow the instructions in the Arch installation guide for installing from within an existing OS. P.S. right before Ubuntu installer loaded (from external HDD) I saw a message saying 'no bootloader present' or something like that. That may be the issue with my original attempt. I'll update on the outcome of this other method for installing Arch.

Comment: @PingPong I don't think you're making it easier for anyone to help you by following very vague theories on a whim and trying a million very invasive things, I'm afraid!